# QT UDP: отправка сообщения на клиент

Tags: qt, udp, qstring

Передо мной стоит задача переслать сообщение формата QString с сервера UDP на клиент. Однако при передаче мной сообщение оно приходит не полностью. Мне кажется, что информация теряется при переводе из QString в QByteArray и обратно. Поэтому на сервере пробую это зафиксировать с помощью QMessage Box. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так:

```
    QString myData = "Message";
    QByteArray myDatagram;
    myDatagram+=myData;
    QDataStream out(&myDatagram, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << myDatagram;
    my_udp->writeDatagram(myDatagram, QHostAddress::LocalHost, 2424);
    myData = QString::fromStdString(myDatagram.toStdString());
    QMessageBox::information(this, "..", myData);
```

Так, например, при попытке переслать слово "Message", отправляется только "age". Или же "o, world!" для "Hello, world!". Пропадают первые три символа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>         QString myData = "Message";
>         QByteArray myDatagram;
>         myDatagram+=myData; //тут Вы напрямую добавляете строку в массив
>         QDataStream out(&myDatagram, QIODevice::WriteOnly); //тут Вы создаете поток для записи в массив
>         out << myDatagram; // тут вы в поток пытаетесь записать массив, т.е. записываете массив в себя
```

Наверно нужно сделать так:

```
QString myData = "Message";
ByteArray myDatagram;
QDataStream out(&myDatagram, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out << myData;
```